# As a developer, is there a way to improve the carbon footprint of my code and how to calculate the carbon emission

Tags: performance

With global warming, I think we all have a role to play and it starts with performance of our code.

- Is there a way to calculate the carbon footprint of a piece of code? (ex. like converting CPU Time or SOQL limit in CO2 consumption)
- Beyond best practices (like avoid SOQL in loop and bulkify code), what are main tips to improve code performance?

Comment: A quick search suggests that [Salesforce is carbon neutral](https://www.salesforce.com/company/sustainability/). Beyond what Salesforce says, there's not really much info for us normal people to go on. Code performance is also a _huge_ topic. About the only general answer to that one is "study up on algorithms and computational complexity".

Comment: I doubt anybody has or will be able to calculate the carbon footprint for a small piece of code in a large product / multi-tenant infrastructure (or at least whether doing something like that would make sense), but the idea of doing this sounds cool. I guess some of the optimization at apex/ force framework level would have factored this at design level. Also, it makes senses to determine carbon footprint at the overall infrastructure level.

Comment: Besides performance, one recommendation often heard (e.g. [here](https://abookapart.com/products/sustainable-web-design/)) is: do computations server-side, because our boxes work much less efficient than cloud computing. This is in direct opposition to Salesforce's recommendation for speed optimisation. My impression is that because Salesforce pays Amazon and others for CPU time, it hopes to transfer as much possible to browsers and have set up Apex execution accordingly. Much today is much faster in Javascript than in Apex. Admins might scour the scheduled jobs page for obsolete jobs.

Comment: In any case, I don't think your question is Salesforce specific. It's similar in many cloud computing contexts. A good place to discuss such is [ClimateAction.tech](https://climateaction.tech/). When we software developers start coding, much might already be out of our hands anyway. Instead we maybe better look how to contribute to products like [Net Zero Cloud](https://www.salesforce.com/products/net-zero-cloud/overview/) and encourage clients to consider the topic.